# htaccess rewrite rule not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I've been trying to fix thousands of 404 errors in Google webmaster using htaccess rewrite but not getting anywhere. I read a lot on it but had no luck so far in implementing it successfully.

The errors reported are in this format:

```
http://sub.example.com/tl/author/admin/page/82
http://sub.example.com/tl/author/admin/page/91
http://sub.example.com/no/author/admin/page/101
```

These are pages created by a translation plugin which I no longer use. "tl", "no" etc are the language folder.

I want to strip the language folder from the url to make it:

```
http://sub.example.com/author/admin/page/82
```

Here is what I entered in htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z][A-Za-z])/author/admin/page/([0-9]+)$ http://sub.example.com/author/admin/page/$2 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I tried many variations of rewrite rule but nothing worked. Then I removed all regex and simply used the full url:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^http://sub.example.com/tl/author/admin/page/82$ http://sub.example.com/author/admin/page/82 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

This didn't work either.

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why it wasn't working. I used *"RedirectMatch 301"* instead with same Regex and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

your best bet would be to query this with your hosting provider. I have had to deal with hosting providers RE issues like this in the past. Some of the hosting servers somehow manage to restrict/override certain setting found within .htaccess.

An example is a Wordpress site hosted on a Windows server, my one hosts do not allow the .htaccess file to change the permalinks in certain ways....